# Get the original datatype values from a vector of AnyValues

Tags: rust, custom-data-type, rust-polars

I can convert many datatypes into the AnyValue enum in Rust Polars. but how do I convert them back to the original  datatypes?

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let df = df!(  "Fruit" => &["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"],
                   "Boolean" => &[true,false,true],
                   "Float64" => &[1.1,321.45,101.445])
    .unwrap();

    // get row 1 of the DataFrame as a vector of AnyValues
    let vec_anyvalue = df.get(1).unwrap();

    // trying to get the actual values:

    // getting the fruit as a String kind of works (get quotation marks too)
    let fruit = vec_anyvalue.get(0).unwrap().to_string();

    // getting the bool or the float value does not ?!

    // ERROR:  the trait `From<&AnyValue<'_>>` is not implemented for `bool`
    let boolvalue: bool = vec_anyvalue.get(1).unwrap().into();
    // ERROR:  the trait `From<AnyValue<'_>>` is not implemented for `f64`
    let floatvalue: f64 = vec_anyvalue.get(2).unwrap().into();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to write a converter yourself:

```
fn to_bool<'a>(v: &AnyValue<'a>) -> bool {
    if let AnyValue::Boolean(b) = v {
        *b
    } else {
        panic!("not a boolean");
    }
}
```

(or a variation returning Option/Result)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works for all my types. Q: Where can I learn about this `if let AnyValue::Boolean(b) = v {  *b  }` way of getting access to the values of the AnyValue enums? [This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) did not explain it ...

Comment: Did you read that part all the way up to "6.3 Concise Control Flow with if let" ? I feel like it's well written and should help understand `if let`. If you did, I don't know what to suggest. Maybe try practicing with your own enums (smaller than this AnyValue), to get a feel for it.

Comment: Thanks @Gnurfos, the `if let` part is clear, what I do not understand how `AnyValue::Boolean(b) = v {  *b  }` populates `b` , which is returned by the function.

Comment: `b` in `AnyValue::Boolean(b)` is a declaration/binding. It's like having `let b = ...`. Then in the body, `*b` is equivalent to `return *b;`

Comment: Thanks ... great Info ... I learned something new ! Q: Where in the Rust Book would this be covered? This is not intuitive for me ...

Comment: That part is shown in 6.2 "patterns that bind to values". The book reads easily, but it's dense, and Rust is complex. I'm afraid you might have to read it slower or give it several passes. You can write your own code along the way to experiment and make sure you get the usefulness of the concepts

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the DataFrame values ​​using Series or AnyValue.

```
// Rust version 1.67.1 ; polars version 0.27.2
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let s0 = Series::new("a", &[1.2, 2.2, 3.3]);
    let s1 = Series::new("b", &[7.6, 1.2]);
    let s2 = Series::new("c", &[4.4, -5.07, 99.3, 55.2]);
    // construct a new ListChunked for a slice of Series.
    let list = Series::new("ListFloat64", &[s0, s1, s2]);

    // construct a few more Series.
    let s0 = Series::new("Fruit", ["Apple", "Apple", "Pear"]);
    let s1 = Series::new("Boolean", [true, false, true]);
    let s2 = Series::new("Float64", [1.1, 321.45, 101.445]);

    let dataframe = DataFrame::new(vec![s0, s1, s2, list])?;

    println!("dataframe:\n{dataframe}\n");

    // I was able to get the DataFrame values ​​using Series.

    let column_string: &Series = dataframe.column("Fruit")?;
    let column_boolean: &Series = dataframe.column("Boolean")?;
    let column_float64: &Series = dataframe.column("Float64")?;
    let column_listfloat64: &Series = dataframe.column("ListFloat64")?;

    // Get rows from columns with into_iter()

    let vec_opt_str: Vec<Option<&str>> = column_string.utf8()?.into_iter().collect();
    let vec_opt_bool: Vec<Option<bool>> = column_boolean.bool()?.into_iter().collect();
    let vec_opt_f64: Vec<Option<f64>> = column_float64.f64()?.into_iter().collect();
    let vec_opt_series: Vec<Option<Series>> = column_listfloat64.list()?.into_iter().collect();

    // Remove intermadiate Options: Vec<Option<Type>> --> Vec<Type>

    let vec_strings: Vec<&str> = get_vec_type(vec_opt_str);
    let vec_boolean: Vec<bool> = get_vec_type(vec_opt_bool);
    let vec_float64: Vec<f64> = get_vec_type(vec_opt_f64);
    let vec_series: Vec<Series> = get_vec_type(vec_opt_series);

    for row in 0..dataframe.height() {
        println!("Show data from row {row}:");

        let value_string: String = vec_strings[row].to_string();
        println!("\tvalue_string: {value_string}");

        let value_bool: bool = vec_boolean[row];
        println!("\tvalue_bool: {value_bool}");

        let value_f64: f64 = vec_float64[row];
        println!("\tvalue_f64: {value_f64}");

        let series: &Series = &vec_series[row];
        let vec_opt_f64_new: Vec<Option<f64>> = series.f64()?.into_iter().collect();
        let vec_float64_new: Vec<f64> = get_vec_type(vec_opt_f64_new);
        println!("\tvec_list_f64: {vec_float64_new:?}\n");
    }

    let row = 1;
    let column = 2;

    println!("Using Vec<AnyValue>, row = {row}, column = {column}:");
    let vec_anyvalue: Vec<AnyValue> = dataframe.get(row).unwrap();
    let floatvalue: f64 = vec_anyvalue.get(column).unwrap().try_extract::<f64>()?;
    println!("floatvalue: {floatvalue}\n");

    println!("Using AnyValue, row = {row}:");
    let anyvalue: AnyValue = dataframe.column("Float64")?.iter().nth(row).unwrap();
    let value_f64 = anyvalue.try_extract::<f64>()?;
    println!("value_f64: {value_f64}");

    Ok(())
}
```

Such that, get_vec_type:

```
/// Remove intermadiate Option
fn get_vec_type<T>(vec_opt_type: Vec<Option<T>>) -> Vec<T> 
    where T: std::default::Default
{
    vec_opt_type
        //.into_no_null_iter() // if we are certain we don't have missing values
        .into_iter()
        .map(|opt_type| opt_type.unwrap_or_default())
        .collect()
}
```

The final result:

```
dataframe:
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ Fruit ┆ Boolean ┆ Float64 ┆ ListFloat64            │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---                    │
│ str   ┆ bool    ┆ f64     ┆ list[f64]              │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ Apple ┆ true    ┆ 1.1     ┆ [1.2, 2.2, 3.3]        │
│ Apple ┆ false   ┆ 321.45  ┆ [7.6, 1.2]             │
│ Pear  ┆ true    ┆ 101.445 ┆ [4.4, -5.07, ... 55.2] │
└───────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────┘

Show data from row 0:
    value_string: Apple
    value_bool: true
    value_f64: 1.1
    vec_list_f64: [1.2, 2.2, 3.3]

Show data from row 1:
    value_string: Apple
    value_bool: false
    value_f64: 321.45
    vec_list_f64: [7.6, 1.2]

Show data from row 2:
    value_string: Pear
    value_bool: true
    value_f64: 101.445
    vec_list_f64: [4.4, -5.07, 99.3, 55.2]

Using Vec<AnyValue>, row = 1, column = 2:
floatvalue: 321.45

Using AnyValue, row = 1:
value_f64: 321.45
```